# Function to read and parse string into Iterator in Rust

Tags: rust

Is there a way to write a function that will look like this:

```rust
fn read_and_iter_u32_line<'a>(mut buf: String) -> Iterator<Item=u32> {
    buf.truncate(0);
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut buf).unwrap();
    buf.split_whitespace()
        .map(|s| s.parse::<u32>().unwrap())
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterators are lazy. This means the data they are operating on needs to exist as long as the iterator itself, but `buf` ceases to exist when the function returns. If we keep `buf` around for longer it can work though.

Writing functions that return complex iterators is tricky at the moment, but it's possible:

```
use std::io;
use std::iter::{Iterator, Map};
use std::str::SplitWhitespace;

fn read_and_iter_u32_line(buf: &mut String) -> Map<SplitWhitespace, fn(&str) -> u32> {
    buf.truncate(0);
    io::stdin().read_line(buf).unwrap();
    buf.split_whitespace().map(parse)
}

fn parse(s: &str) -> u32 {
    s.parse::<u32>().unwrap()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterators are lazy, therefore they must borrow their input:

- this requires that their input lives longer than they do
- this requires, for safety reason, that the borrowing relationship be exposed at function boundaries

The former point requires that the `buf` be passed as a reference and not a value.

The latter point prevents you from returning a generic `Iterator<Item=u32>` (even boxed) because it hides the borrowing relationship between the returned iterator and the passed in buffer. So instead you must be explicit:

```
use std::io;

fn read_and_iter_u32_line<'a>(buf: &'a mut String)
    -> std::iter::Map<std::str::SplitWhitespace<'a>, fn(&'a str) -> u32>
{
    fn convert(s: &str) -> u32 { s.parse().unwrap() }

    buf.truncate(0);
    io::stdin().read_line(buf).unwrap();

    buf.split_whitespace().map(convert)
}

fn main() {
    let mut buf = "".to_string();
    for i in read_and_iter_u32_line(&mut buf) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

*Note: actually, the lifetime annotation can be elided, but I have exposed it here to highlight why the generic iterator is not possible.*